# Adding object to existing array overwrites value

Tags: javascript

I'm looping through 2 arrays and create an object which I want to add to my array data.

In the first iteration I get

```
data: {
    "raucher": "true"
}
```

After the second iteration and adding the 2nd object I get

```
data: {
       "alter": "65", 
       "raucher": false <--- why false?
}
```

What's going wrong?

```
  var arr = new Array();

  for (var i = 0; i < componentsLength; i++) {

      var path = formComponentsArray[i].path;

      for (var z = 0; z < payloadLength; z++) {

        var fieldID = payload[z].fieldID.toLowerCase();

        if(path === fieldID) {
          var value = payload[z].value;
          var obj = {};
          obj[path] = value;
          arr["data"] = { ...obj };
        }

      }

  }
```

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). I don't see any way you could end up with more than one property in `arr.data` given you're creating a new object every time (`var obj = {};`) adding **one** property to it (`obj[path] = value;`) and then **replacing** `arr.data` with a shallow copy of that object: `arr["data"] = { ... obj };`. If there's a second property on the object, it's added by code that isn't...

Comment: ...in the question. Separately, why are you creating non-element properties on an array? Normally that's an anti-pattern. I don't see anything in the code in the question that suggests `arr` should be an array rather than a simple object. `arr["data"] = { ...obj }` is just using it as a simple object, not using any array features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This segment of your code is wrong

```
       if(path === fieldID) {
          var value = payload[z].value;
          var obj = {};
          obj[path] = value;
          arr["data"] = { ...obj };
```

You are destroying the whole of `arr["data"]` and replacing it with an object that can only have one key.

Can you see that what is written above is identical in effect to:

```
   if(path === fieldID) {
      arr["data"] = { [path]:payload[z].value };
   }
```

#### Did you mean this?

```
   if(path === fieldID) {
      arr["data"][path] = payload[z].value ;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! What a mistake...